# Is $e^a$ always algebraic for transcendental $a$?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

From Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem, it is known that $e^a$ for non-zero algebraic $a$ is always transcendental. But if $a$ is transcendental, is the opposite ($e^a \in \mathbb A$) always true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There are [uncountably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) many transcendental $a\in\Bbb R$, each with a different $e^a$, of which only countably many are algebraic.

Comment: And a famous example is [Gelfond's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant).